# How to show mysql data in html form fields one by one

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am a new in Php I want to show mysql data on HTML form one by one, I means when i click on Next button next record show in html form. Please help me on this issue.

Khizar Hayat

Comment: Can you provide more details? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not into php, but found a good example in my opinion.

```
<?php 
    include 'configMembers.php'; 
    include 'opendb.php'; 

    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name"; 
    $result=mysql_query($sql); 
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result); 
    ?> 
    <form method=post> 
    <?php 
    $id=$row['id']; 
    $sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET password='$password' where id='$id'"; 
    $result=mysql_query($sql); 
    ?>
```

And then for the magic:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<? echo $row['username'] ?>
<input type="text" name="password" value="<? echo $row['password'] ?>
```

Comment: It should also have a input type of ID too, but forgot to add it. But I hope this might put you the correct way. Also if it answered your question dont forget to press "Answered" :-)